# Spock mock - set and get parameter

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm using atlassian's maven in my project and want to implement tests in spock framework. I have a problem with `Mock` classes from maven (for example class `Issue` - it has some private value like `key` or `summary` and there is not method like `setKey` and `setSummary`).

I want to `Mock()` `Issue` object, set there some value and then get it (there is `getKey()` and  `getSummary()`).

My code looks like:

```
class WriterSpec extends Specification {

    def returnValue() {
        given:
            Issue g = Mock(key: "exampleKey")
            String response = g.getKey()
        expect:
            response == "exampleKey"
    }
}
```

If I tried to run tests from IDE there is an error(there is no problem with `Issue` object in java classes, just in groovy):

```
Information:Groovyc: While compiling tests of exampleProject:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue due to missing dependency org/ofbiz/core/entity/GenericValue
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:391)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getDeclaredMethods(ClassNode.java:872)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getMethods(ClassNode.java:887)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecialMethodCall.checkIsConditionBlock(SpecialMethodCall.java:194)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecialMethodCall.parse(SpecialMethodCall.java:151)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitMethodCallExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBinaryExpression(CodeVisitorSupport.java:146)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitBinaryExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:150)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitBinaryExpression(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:98)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visitDeclarationExpression(DeepBlockRewriter.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.DeclarationExpression.visit(DeclarationExpression.java:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:196)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.doVisitExpressionStatement(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:146)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.doVisitExpressionStatement(DeepBlockRewriter.java:61)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visitExpressionStatement(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.StatementReplacingVisitorSupport.replace(StatementReplacingVisitorSupport.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.visit(AbstractDeepBlockRewriter.java:71)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.DeepBlockRewriter.visit(DeepBlockRewriter.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpecRewriter.visitAnyBlock(SpecRewriter.java:311)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.SetupBlock.accept(SetupBlock.java:32)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.Method.accept(Method.java:70)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.model.Spec.accept(Spec.java:113)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.processSpec(SpockTransform.java:77)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform$Impl.visit(SpockTransform.java:64)
    at org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform.visit(SpockTransform.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:136)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:156)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.access$000(InProcessGroovyc.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:85)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and if I tried to run tests from console (by using `atlas-mvn clean test`):

```
Running example.WriterSpec
wrz 28, 2017 10:51:35 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap invoke
INFO: Configuring com.athaydes.spockframework.report.SpockReportExtension
wrz 28, 2017 10:51:35 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap invoke
INFO: SpockReports config loaded: [com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.reportFileExtension:md, com.athayde
s.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.specTemplateFile:/templateReportCreator/spec-template.md, com.athaydes.spockframe
work.report.IReportCreator:com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.Te
mplateReportCreator.summaryTemplateFile:/templateReportCreator/summary-template.md, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlRepo
rtCreator.summaryReportCss:spock-summary-report.css, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.template.TemplateReportCreator.summaryFileName:s
ummary.md, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator.featureReportCss:spock-feature-report.css, com.athaydes.spockfr
amework.report.hideEmptyBlocks:false, com.athaydes.spockframework.report.outputDir:build/spock-reports]
wrz 28, 2017 10:51:35 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap invoke
INFO: Loading settings for reportCreator of type com.athaydes.spockframework.report.internal.HtmlReportCreator
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.718 sec <<< FAILURE!
returnValue(example.WriterSpec)  Time elapsed: 0.05 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/search/FieldComparatorSource
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2911)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
        at example.WriterSpec.returnValue(WriterSpec.groovy:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.search.FieldComparatorSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

I did a little bit of research but it didn't help. I have no idea what is a problem and why it doesn't work. What should I do to fix it?

@UPDATE dependency from pom file:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-tests</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spock-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Overrides the Groovy version specified by spock-core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Creates the test report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.athaydes</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Did you add the missing dependency?

Comment: @Opal I edited my post and put there dependency

Comment: No, no. The message is saying there's missing ofbiz dependency - did you added to pom.xml?

Comment: I put every dependencies from my pom to my post so it wasn't there. I added it https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ofbiz/ofbcore-jira-entity/2.1.8 to my pom but it doesn't help (there is the same error)

Comment: @Opal I added dependency to apache lucene and there is no errors. Now problem is that in line `response == "exampleKey"`  `response` is just `null` (from my test class `WriterSpec`)

Comment: @Opal is there any mistake in set value to `Mock()` object? (`Mock(field: value)`)?

Comment: Cool, now see my answer, however this test checks actually nothing.

Comment: Yes, this not how Mock works. See my answer (once again).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to test `returnIssueKeyWithPrefix` only:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class LolSpec extends Specification {

    def 'whatever'() {
        given:
        def prefixer = new Prefixer()
        def issue = Mock(Issue) {
            getKey() >> '1234'
        }

        when:
        def withPrefix = prefixer.returnIssueKeyWithPrefix(issue)

        then:
        withPrefix == 'prefix1234'
    }
}

class Issue {
    String getKey() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException('No!')
    }
}

class Prefixer {
    String returnIssueKeyWithPrefix(Issue issue) {
        return "prefix${issue.key}"
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible that I'm totally wrong but this what I wanted to do is:
-create `Issue` object with `key` value (can not do it by constructor)
-use this object as parameter in another method and check result (result depends on `key` value from this `Issue` object

Comment: Could u put there a little example please?

Comment: @tombobby, if there's no constructor available you won't create the mock this way. Actually, if the constructor was available it wouldn't make any sense to test it this way. What is `Issue` fully qualified class name?

Comment: It is just this class https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.2.2/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html
and i have my own method which has `Issue` object as parameter, it should just return `issueKey` value

Comment: @tombobby, so pass there a Mock in a way I constructed it.

Comment: I'm just have a method `returnIssueKeyWithPrefix(Issue issue){return "prefix"+issue.getKey()`;} Could you explain me how to test it? (its just simply example)